# Mysterious hidden files in C:\Windows -- are they malicious?

Tags: windows, security, malware

A few months ago, I noticed two strange hidden files in `C:\Windows`. They had seemingly random alphanumeric names, no file extensions, and seemingly random binary content. I didn't think much of it at the time.

A few days ago I once again found myself in the Windows folder. To my surprise, many more of these files have appeared!

Output of `dir /AH`:

```
08/04/2004  02:56 AM                28 1cdef1b1d5f5e1k
08/04/2004  02:56 AM                28 1cdef8prlgmmdpq
08/04/2004  02:56 AM                28 1cdefmcdj7ddt1k
08/04/2004  02:56 AM                28 2buvf2dlt8cfv8r
08/04/2004  02:56 AM                18 2buvf8t1thlvm8r
08/04/2004  02:56 AM                28 2buvf8x2cwvvm8r
08/04/2004  02:56 AM                28 2buvfsq1nbrpg8r
08/04/2004  02:56 AM                28 2buvfsudb8cfv8r
08/04/2004  02:56 AM                28 5xyafsy1wki8hbc
08/04/2004  02:56 AM                28 nnwkffpbl4umq4
```

Note that they all have the same creation date (August 4th). The 28-byte files all begin with the byte sequence `0x64 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00` -- probably a header -- which implies that this isn't just random, buggy garbage data. (I'm refraining from posting the full contents of any file in case it somehow contains encoded sensitive data.)

The last modified dates of the file were all relatively recent: December 18th 2021, if I recall correctly. Unfortunately my investigations modified the last modified dates so I can't confirm that.

I can't shake the feeling that these files are malicious, but my laptop hasn't displayed any signs of infection. Over the past 2 days, I've been using Process Monitor to scan for any access to these files. I haven't noticed anything unusual. I've run full scans with Windows Defender (including offline scans); no malware was detected. `sfc /scannow` also gives my system a clear bill of health.

Does anyone know what these files are? Am I right to be concerned, or am I being a hypochondriac?

Comment: Try running Disk Cleanup.  Select "Cleanup System Files" and when the dialogue window comes up, select all categories for cleanup. See if the files go away. They are not on my computer.

Comment: @John Unfortunately I've already tried that. It didn't remove the files.

Comment: @MGuy Any update on this? I assume you have cleared things up by now.